# Email Alert when Child Record Value does not match with Parent

Tags: apex, trigger

I am planning to write a method in a trigger when there is a mismatch of fields on Parent and Child. The trigger is written on Parent Object.

Thoughts on how do I query the data based on the above condition?

Comment: you could share your code whatever you have tried so far

Comment: I tried writing a method to the trigger handler class which exists already, but not sure about how I could query the data. Can anyone suggest how I could get the records based on criteria above?

Comment: You could go through trailhead on writing trigger or handler